# Root Loci Breakaway points

Tags: control-system

my question is regarding if the breakaway points exist or not. Do they only exist if 2 poles or 2 zeros are next to each other? Example if their are poles at -1 and -2 the breakaway point would be at -1.5? But if there was a pole at -1 and a zero at -2 then the breakaway point wouldn't exist? Is this correct? And if so, are they any other cases in which a breakaway point would or would not exist? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Breakaway points signify the points where the loci of poles of a system meet and branch away from the real axis and into complex space to terminate at open-loop zeros in the plot, or those at infinity. There are also break-in points where the loci of complex poles rejoin the real axis and approach zeros.

When sketching a root locus plot, valid regions of the plot that lie on the real axis are the regions to the left of an odd number of poles and zeros. When such a region exists between 2 poles, such that their loci have no where else to go but towards each other, it is guaranteed that both loci will meet at some point (determined by the roots of `dK/ds`) in that region and break away from the real axis to approach either some explicit zero or an implicit zero at infinity along known asymptotes.

Trying to answer your questions:

- There are no breakaway points between zeros; you may have break-in points though, as the loci of other poles terminate at these zeros.
- There is no guarantee that a breakaway point will occur exactly halfway between 2 poles; the position of the zeros (if any) influence this.
- If the portion of the real axis between the pole at -1 and the zero at -2 is part of the locus, as determined by the rule I mentioned earlier, then yes the pole will travel towards the nearest zero and there will be no breakaway points between them; in fact there can be no breakaway points between a pole and a zero.
- You may have a double pole (e.g. s = -2 twice) and the loci of both poles will break away from their very beginning at s = -2. You may also have complex 'breakaway' points, where 2 loci meet in complex space and diverge. I dont know of any other.

Answer (score 0):

A break point will exist any time there is a more than one pole on the real axis.

Break points are found by by taking the derivative of the characteristic equation and then setting it equal to zero and solving it.

In the example you gave (x+1)(x+2) is your characteristic equation or x^2 + 3x +2.

The derivative is 2x + 3.

The solution to 2x + 3 = 0 is -1.5 or the break point.

This solution lies on the root locust making it the break point. Sometimes there are cases where there are many solutions but not all of them lie on the root locust. In that case only the solutions that lie on the root locust are the break points.